# Usage of 'and' in a sentence

Tags: conjunctions, determiners, progressive-aspect

> 1. The results of the infection of malaria are the enlargement of spleen and capillaries in the brain are blocked.
> 2. The results of the infection of malaria are the enlargement of spleen and capillaries in the brain being blocked.

In these two sentence above, how should I use the conjunction 'and' ?
Can I use it to join noun and sentence?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "join noun and sentence." Can you enlsrge your question to explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are difficult to parse, as it is natural to read as "enlargement of the spleen and capillaries", and when the rest of the sentence follows one has to go back and reparse the sentence (this is called a garden path sentence)

The first example is arguably wrong, since "capillaries of the brain are blocked" isn't a noun phrase. The second is correct, but has the potential to confuse.

Perhaps a rephrasing is the best solution:

> There are two main effects of a malaria infection: The spleen is enlarged, and capillaries in the brain are blocked.